# How can I convert Image to Matrix and then Matrix to Bitmap in EmguCV?

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

I am trying to do something like the following:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
const string path = @"lena.png";

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Image<Bgr, byte> color = new Image<Bgr, byte>(path);

    Matrix<byte> matrix = new Matrix<byte>(color.Rows, color.Cols);

    matrix.Data = color.ToMatrix();// just an analogy

    pictureBox1.Image = col.Bitmap;
    pictureBox2.Image = gray.Bitmap;
}
}
```

How can I convert `Image` to `Matrix` in EmguCV?

How can I convert `Matrix` to `Bitmap`?

Comment: If I read the docs right, they both inherit from `CvArray`, so maybe the `CopyTo` member? Btw, since the Image is 3-channel (BGR), then the Matrix should be as well for it to work.

Comment: OK, so which one is it -- `Image` to `Matrix` or `Matrix` to `Bitmap`? ;) I just got my C# + EmguCV env set up (as I haven't really touched C# since the early days) to be able to give you a proper answer, and the shifting target is honestly a bit discouraging (I recall reading a meta post of yours where someone pointed this out as well).

Comment: @DanMašek, your 1st comment solved my 1st problem. Now, I am stuck with the second one.

Comment: @DanMašek, I am rolling back the question to previous one.

Comment: @DanMašek, by the way, I am deleting my profile. So, don't be so tensed about meta.

Comment: No problem, thanks. It just came to my mind ;) And I've had it happen few times that I've spent time writing up a comprehensive answer, only to have the OP make it look like irrelevant rambling by later completely changing the original question. No offence meant.

Comment: Heh, I was wondering what you were trying to say in your profile message.... that explains it. I've been noticing this place going downhill lately, but maybe there's no need to take such extreme measures yet? At least in my perspective, this was a useful question once we settled on what it's about -- and you motivated me enough to dig in a language I haven't used for ages, and set up OpenCV bingings for the 4th language (already have 10 different versions ready for Python). Thanks for that, it was a useful excercise. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Converting `Image` to `Matrix`

The important thing to notice here is that both [`Image`](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/3.4.3/document/html/a8929aab-99c5-79cf-385c-dcec7769fea1.htm) and [`Matrix`](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/3.4.3/document/html/ec1c8c3f-a99c-a082-e794-bb74db961c60.htm) inherit from [`CvArray`](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/3.4.3/document/html/7fc0991d-4a1a-4010-3c3f-f68fcf148838.htm). That means it is possible to use the (inherited) method [`CopyTo`](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/3.4.3/document/html/c4facc43-cefc-9617-a4c4-db4aa3d1bfbf.htm) to copy the data from an `Image` instance to a `Matrix` instance of identical depth and dimensions.

**NB:** There are 3 dimensions of relevance -- width, height, and channel count.

```
Image<Bgr, byte> color = ... ; // Initialized in some manner

Matrix<byte> matrix = new Matrix<byte>(color.Rows, color.Cols, color.NumberOfChannels);

color.CopyTo(matrix);
```

**NB:** There's a cost involved with this approach, due to the necessity to make a copy of the entire data array.

### Converting `Matrix` to `Bitmap`

This one is actually quite simple. `Matrix` inherits the property [`Mat`](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/3.4.3/document/html/33e1271c-2f87-3531-d088-dbbe73e4cbf7.htm), which returns a [`Mat`](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/3.4.3/document/html/2ec33afb-1d2b-cac1-ea60-0b4775e4574c.htm) header (meaning a thin wrapper around an existing data array) for the array data. Since this just creates a header, it's very quick (no copies involved).

**NB:** Due to being a header, I assume based on my experience with the C++ API (even though this doesn't seem documented) that the `Mat` object is valid as long as the underlying `Matrix` object stays in scope.

`Mat` provides a [`Bitmap`](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/3.4.3/document/html/28771a88-bafc-6ed9-836b-1dd35aca3602.htm) property, which behaves identically to [`Image.Bitmap`](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/3.4.3/document/html/792e25d7-4ae8-52c3-eadb-c05ee7b7919f.htm).

```
Bitmap b = matrix.Mat.Bitmap;
```

The other option is to use the same approach as before to copy the data back to the `Image` instance.

```
matrix.CopyTo(color);
```

Then you could use the `Bitmap` property (fast, but requires the `Image` instance to live as long as you use the `Bitmap`).

```
Bitmap b = color.Bitmap;
```

Another alternative would be to use the [`ToBitmap`](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/3.4.3/document/html/058c70e1-9b5c-5e54-0e43-63a761ede9f7.htm) method, which copies the data, and therefore doesn't carry the dependency on the source `Image` instance.

```
Bitmap b = color.ToBitmap();
```

---

Source used for testing:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using Emgu.CV;
using Emgu.CV.Structure;
// ============================================================================
namespace CS1 {
// ============================================================================
class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Image<Bgr, byte> color = new Image<Bgr, byte>(2, 2);
        for (int r = 0; r < color.Rows; r++) {
            for (int c = 0; c < color.Cols; c++) {
                int n = (c + r * color.Cols) * 3;
                color[r, c] = new Bgr(n, n+1, n+2);
            }
        }

        Matrix<byte> matrix = new Matrix<byte>(color.Rows, color.Cols, color.NumberOfChannels);

        color.CopyTo(matrix);

        Bitmap b = matrix.Mat.Bitmap;

        matrix.CopyTo(color);

        b = color.Bitmap;

        b = color.ToBitmap();
    }
}
// ============================================================================
} // namespace CS1
// ============================================================================
```

The CMake file I used to generate a solution to compile this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.11)
project(CS1 VERSION 0.1.0 LANGUAGES CSharp)

add_executable(cs1
    src/test.cs
)

set_property(TARGET cs1
    PROPERTY VS_DOTNET_TARGET_FRAMEWORK_VERSION "v4.6.1"
)

set_property(TARGET cs1 
    PROPERTY VS_DOTNET_REFERENCES
    "System"
    "System.Drawing"
)

set_target_properties(cs1 PROPERTIES 
    VS_DOTNET_REFERENCE_emgu_cv_world "deps/Emgu.CV.World.dll"
)
```